# Selenium Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Angular Modal Dialog

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm attempting to interact with a Angular BootStrap Modal Dialog hidden in a Div that pops up on  clicking a link and Selenium is throwing  the

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible.
```

Since its not a JavaScript Alert and not a new Window I cant use the Alert or WindowHandles Api's.

My flow goes

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Promotional Code']")).click(); //link in menu that launches the dialog box 

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //I do an implicit wait to make sure the dialog box loads 

driver.findElement(By.id("promobox")).sendKeys("test");//Attempting to enter test in dialog box, but error gets thrown.
```

I can use a

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("promobox")).isDisplayed());
```

and it will print true on the console but When I attempt to do a

```
driver.findElement(By.id("promobox")).sendKeys("test");
```

I get the exception.

Any Ideas? or Help would be greatly appreciated. I am using the latest version SWD 2.45 and FF 35.01 Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm getting a feeling that `implicitlyWait()` is not what you think it is. Try running a `PauseAction` (as seen in https://github.com/seleniumQuery/seleniumQuery/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/seleniumquery/browser/BrowserFunctions.java#L111 ) and then you may get what you need.

Comment: Thank You !this kinda gets me in the right direction i Can now at least click the Cancel and Submit buttons in the pop up doing this

Comment: Thank You !this kinda gets me in the right direction i Can now at least click the Cancel and Submit buttons in the pop up doing this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Promotional Code']")).click();
Actions promobox=  new Actions(driver);
promobox.pause(30);                                              promobox.build().perform();  but if I try to input anything into the box by doing promobox.sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='promobox']")), "test");      i get a    MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException  any ideas?